# How to change the default ports of WSO2 3.2.0 APIM?

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 3.2.0 APIM on Windows platform and have a need to change the default HTTP/HTTPS ports from 9443/9763 to 9080/9090. This means that the offset won't work for me. I did some searching here and got some hits. However, some answers are quite old and some answers don't seem to work with 3.2.0.

The most promising answer is to update the connectors in <API-M_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml. I tried it, but it didn't work. When I started up WSO2, the bootstrap showed messages on the console that it detected the configuration changes and the ports got reverted back to the default ones.

The messages on the console look like this

```
C:\Programs\wso2am-3.2.0\bin>wso2server.bat --run
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Java\openjdk-1.8.0.191-1.b12.redhat
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Programs\WSO2AM~1.0\bin\..
[2021-04-26 22:22:18,514]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository\conf\tomcat\catalina-server.xml
[2021-04-26 22:22:18,514]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory C:\Programs\WSO2AM~1.0\bin\..
[2021-04-26 22:22:19,802]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Writing Metadata Entries...
andes [org.wso2.andes.wso2.internal.QpidBundleActivator] INFO : Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
callhome [org.wso2.carbon.callhome.internal.CallHomeActivator] DEBUG : Activating CallHome agent
[2021-04-26 22:22:29,530]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
...
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From API Manager v3.0 onwards, you only need to change the deployment.toml file which resides in the wso2am-3.2.0/repository/conf location. You can't change any xml files that reside in the conf directory. To change the ports, you can add the following config in the deployment.toml

```
[transport.https.properties]
port = 9080
[transport.http.properties]
port = 9090
```

The port offset will append to these base values.